# If F→G is a consequence of F, then so is ¬G→¬F. A direct proof?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Homework question (introduction to logic):
"If $F \to G$ is a consequence of $\mathcal F$, then so is $\lnot G \to \lnot F$. We refer to this rule as $\to$-contrapositive. Verify this rule by giving formal proof."

---

My attempt at proving it (by contradiction):

$H: \lnot G \to \lnot F$
$(1)\quad\mathcal F\vdash F \to G \quad$ {assumption}
$(2)\quad\mathcal F \cup \{ \lnot H \} \vdash \lnot ( \lnot G \to \lnot F) \quad$ {assumption for contradiction}
$(3)\quad\mathcal F \cup \{ \lnot H \} \vdash \lnot(\lnot F \lor G)\quad$ {from $\vdash \lnot (\phi \to \psi) \equiv \psi \lor \lnot \phi$, and line: 2}
$(4)\quad\mathcal F \cup \{ \lnot H \} \vdash F \land \lnot G\quad \quad${from deMorgan's Law and line: 3}
$(5)\quad\mathcal F \cup \{ \lnot H \} \vdash F \quad \quad$ {$\land$ - elimination, line: 4}
$(6)\quad\mathcal F \cup \{ \lnot H \} \vdash \lnot G \quad \quad$ {$\land$ - elimination, line: 4}
$(7)\quad\mathcal F \cup \{ \lnot H \} \vdash G \quad \quad$ {$\to$ - elimination, lines: 1, 5}
$(8)\quad\mathcal F \cup \{ \lnot H \} \vdash G \land \lnot G\quad \quad$ {$\land$ - introduction, lines: 6, 7}
$\quad \quad\mathcal F \vdash H  .\square$

question 1: Can you verify if it's OK/ give hints what's wrong if it's not?
question 2: Is there a direct proof?

[edited]

Comment: When you ask about formal proof homework, you _always_ need to specify exactly which formal system you want to carry out the proof in. There are many different systems of formal logic that are equivalent in the sense that they prove the same theorems, but with formal proofs that can look radically different. It looks rather strange that you're apparently working in a system that allows both De Morgan's laws _and_ things like "$\land$-elimination" to be primitive proof steps at the same time.

Comment: ... not to mention that in line 3 you appear to be appealing to a _semantic_ fact ($\vDash$), which is not something one would expect to find in a formal proof.

Comment: @HenningMakholm in comment to line 3 I meant that I'm 'allowed' to use that 'rule' because I derived it earlier. The system I'm using is propositional logic with minimal set of axioms: conjunction/disjunction introduction/elimination, modus ponens, double negation elimination, law of the excluded middle (I hope I listed them all, but am not sure).

Comment: x @Pawel: In general you need to _show_ your axioms instead of simply _naming_ them; different systems tend to use the same names for axioms that do more-or-less the same high-level job but are phrased differently in ways that matter here. Also note that "propositional logic" is the name of the _family_ of systems that have the same axioms, not a (generally understandable) name for a _particular_ system.

Comment: x @Pawel: If your rule in line 3 is a derived rule, then you should have notated it with $\vdash$ instead of $\vDash$ -- the two-horizontal-lines turnstile is generally used for semantic reasoning about interpretations and model, whereas $\vdash$ is for "a formal proof exists".

Comment: @HenningMakholm ...after some thought: Isn't my set of axioms defined already by set of rules $\mathcal F $ that has consequence $F \to G$ ? Is any additional axiom listing really needed?

Comment: x @Pawel: I agree that we don't need to see $\mathcal F$, but what I'm asking about is the _logical_ inference rules for the kind of formal proofs you're constructing. That's the kind of things that have names like "$\land-elimination". There are several different sets of such rules you _might_ be using -- it sounds like you have been taught only one of them and therefore think the details of what you were taught is implied by saying "formal proof". But the answer you need is very sensitive to minor details in the rules that can be different from textbook to textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct proof has the outline:

$H: \lnot G \to \lnot F$
$(1)\quad\mathcal F\vdash F \to G \quad$ {assumption}
$(2)\quad\mathcal F \vdash \lnot G$ {assumption for direct proof}
...
$(n)\quad\mathcal F \vdash \lnot F$ {reasons...}

The steps are very simlar to your proof by contradiction. I leave the details to be filled in by the reader.

Comment: Your answer helped me to write a nice short proof. Thanks.